# insert video(bytes) sent from device in gridfs in mongodb node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am new to gridfs mongodb and creating a POST service to recieve the bytes(of video) and want to save the bytes in mongodb. I have studied gridfs, but couldn't got the clear picture. I have written the code, but I don't know if it is good enough to handle large files. Or how to recieve the bytes from the device and store in gridfs any optimal way? or anyother way to store video(bytes)? Any help is very much appreciated. below is the code.

```
var bytes = [];
bytes = req.param('video');
var db = new Db('myDB', new Server('localhost', 27017,{w:1}));

db.open(function(err, db) {
    // Our file ID
    var fileId = new ObjectID();

    // Open a new file
    var gridStore = new GridStore(db, fileId, 'w');
    gridStore.open(function(err, gridStore) {

        //Write a buffer
        gridStore.write(new Buffer(bytes), function(err, gridStore) {

            // Close the
            gridStore.close(function(err, result) {

                // Read back all the written content and verify the correctness
                GridStore.read(db, fileId, function(err, fileData) {

                    console.log(fileData);
                    db.close();
                });
            });
        });
        // });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided example for  base64  string insertion in mongodb. You can use it and apply it for video byte string. just replace string of that.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
    var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    var streamifier = require('streamifier');

    // create or use an existing mongodb-native db instance.
    // for this example we'll just create one:
    var db = new mongo.Db('mydb', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));

    // make sure the db instance is open before passing into `Grid`
    db.open(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return handleError(err);
        var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);


    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        mode: 'w',
        filename: 'dummy_video',  //        files.contentType  (Optional. A valid MIME type for the document.)
        content_type: 'video/mp4' //          files.filename (Optional. A human-readable name for the document.)
    });    


        var vidoBase64 = 'data:video/mp4;base64,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';//The base64 has a Video
    // if you are getting this byte string into chunks you need to man


    var byte_string = vidoBase64.substr(23);//The base64 has a imageURL
    var buffer = new Buffer(byte_string);   //new Buffer(b64string, 'base64');  you can use base64 encoding with creating new buffer string
    var response = streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(writestream);  // returns response which is having all information regarding saved byte string
    var lastInsertedFileId = response._store.fileId;  // now you can store it into another document for future use.
    console.log(lastInsertedFileId);   // this is _id saved in mydb.fs.files
         //Now you can check mydb.fs.files and mydb.fs.chunks document.




    });
```

Now you can extract complete chunks of same input data through following code---

```
        var output = '';
    var readStream = gfs.createReadStream({
        _id: lastInsertedFileId    // this id was stored in db when inserted a video stream above
    });
    readStream.on("data", function(chunk) {
        output += chunk;
    });

    // dump contents to console when complete
    readStream.on("end", function() {
        console.log("Final Output");
        console.log(output);
    });
```

Modify code according to your requirements.

Thanks

Comment: Thankyou. I need to know what is the filename and what would be the content type in case of video. I think these are also optional parmaeter, rite? Also how to get the _id unique value?

Comment: figured out the _id value I will use the object id of mongodb. I have some more queries,you have mentioned to replace the byte string for video, that byte string will also be converted to 'base64'? How to check if the stream has successfully done with storing the data, any status, for e.g req.on("end")

Comment: @Java_NewBie, I have updated some lines of code as per your concerns and requirement. Might be helpful to get your requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thankyou. I will try this. Also if the writeStream is successfully done I have used writeStream.on("finish") to check if the stream is successfully done. Is this ok?

Comment: streamifier.createReadStream() is a synchronous function, so you will get response just as above line of code, no need to apply on("finish") here.

Comment: Thankyou it worked. Actually when I send a request It save two files and two chunks, i think the request is called two times, and if i use writeStream.on("finish") then it save one file and a chunk. I think this is the problem?

Comment: Thanks  Java_NewBie. its great to hear from you. Now we have achieved  it cumulatively.

Comment: Thanks Dineshaws you have helped me a lot :). I just need one more answer of my above comment "when I send a post request It save two files and two chunks, i think the request is called two times by itself, and if i use writeStream.on("finish") then it save one file and a chunk. it means the request is now called one time. Is this correct?" and how to make the multipart request or is it important to make the multipart request?

Comment: let me know one thing that either video bytes getting in chunks or you make it through 'fs'.

Comment: No I am not making it through 'fs', I am getting video bytes through json and converting it to base64 and then save it. but now it would be also the multipart request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73845/discussion-between-java-newbie-and-dineshaws).

Comment: as the notification issue in chat I am asking over here :). I just need an info if device send me the multipart request with video bytes, then how to handle this thing? or just we have to pass the bytes as now we are doing? currently I am assuming device is sending me the video bytes(video/mov) as a multipart request, so how can I do this? Is I can use the same implemetation as above?

Comment: I have also created a quesiton on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355484/send-a-multipart-request-from-a-device-to-server-in-node-js

Comment: I have followed this answer the files are getting uploaded to mongoDB in fs.chunks and fs.files but the downloaded video file is not opening in media player...