# send a multipart request from a device to server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am receiving a video bytes from a device, and it should be a multipart request. Its a post api which is created in node.js. How can I recieve a multipart request in post api in node.js. Below is the code which is currently saving video bytes.

```
app.js
app.post('/saveVideo',service.saveVideo);

routes.js(class service method saveVideo)
var video_byte_string = req.param('videoByteStr');
var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({mode:'w',content_type: 'video/mov'});
var buffer = new Buffer(video_byte_string).toString('base64');
var response = streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: have you tried my answer? if yes, please tell me what is the outcome of this?

Comment: @Dineshaws  no I haven't. I will try it today and I will tell you the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a separator after video bye string like following

*if byte string are - 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';*

then you need to append any separator(#####) like this to identify end of complete string

*now your request string will be like this - 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'+'#####';*

Now your request string having a end separator(#####) from which you can identify your complete chunks

```
var video_byte_string = req.param('videoByteStr');
isCorrectString = false;
data_stream += video_byte_string;
var n = data_stream.lastIndexOf("#####");
if (n === -1) {
    var steamArr= data_stream.split("#####");
    var completeByteString = steamArr[0];
    isCorrectString = true;
}

if(isCorrectString) {

    var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({mode:'w',content_type: 'video/mov'});
    var buffer = new Buffer(completeByteString).toString('base64');
    var response = streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(writeStream);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have one query, does req.param('videoByteStr') recieve the request only one time? it means it will receive only one chunk?

Comment: are you using steaming? If yes then you will receive in chunks

Comment: Yes, If you are not using steaming means all the video byes will be receive in  single chunk. To receive chunks i have provided a simple example if you are getting in chunks